# How to tell Google Closure Compiler in simple mode that particular function name could be compressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-closure-compiler

Google Closure Compiler does it with ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS option, but I can not use it, since I use jQuery. So, I have to use SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS, but I would like to compress names of some functions.

```
function myLongFunctionName(response) {
 // do something here
}

myLongFunctionName(text);
```

I am OK to have `myLongFunctionName` changed to `a` (or whatever Closure Compiler chooses). But I don't see any [annotation](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler), which could help me. How could I do it?

Comment: externs does not work with jQuery ?

Comment: @Hacketo, it returns a lot of errors, when jQuery is given as externs_url.

Comment: I used it with a jQuery history plugin and it was ok. (also with an extern for the plugin)

Comment: @Hacketo, Closure Compiler even suggests to compile jQuery 1.7.2 (see URL dropdown at http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home), but it is old version of jQuery again.

Comment: I don't use jQuery anymore, but jQuery can work without beeing compiled with closure. For what your want to achieve, the only way that I see is to export your function as 'a' and after compilation, replace all your function calls with 'a', I've not a big experience with closure, I don't know how/if you could do this with the compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If function is local, then Google Closure Compiler renames it. I've moved my code into

```
(function(){

  function myLongFunctionName(response) {
   // do something here
  }

  myLongFunctionName(text);

})()
```

In result, it is compressed also.

Comment: you could wrap it with `(function(){ ... })()` if you want to add a scope (instead of the `document.ready`).